# Onde colocar a regra de negócio no angular?

Tags: angularjs, orientação-a-objetos, regra-de-negócio

Gosto muito de programar web e mobile apps com angularjs.
Mas estou cansado de espalhar minhas regras de negócio por controller e factorys.
Sinto falta de poder criar meus objetos com suas respectivas responsabilidades, alem de controllers serviços também, como faço em outras linguagens.

Como eu poderia ter uma abordagem como essa, orentada a objetos com responsabilidades isoladas, no angular?
Alguém já implementou assim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem sua questão (e se minha experiência puder responder bem) eu diria que você não está fazendo errado. Em Angular, as coisas ficam meio "espalhadas" mesmo, a grande questão é saber bem como "organizar a bagunça".

Cada um desses elementos (e que são muitos) possuem finalidades bem específicas, que muitas vezes são completamente ignoradas. Seja por tutoriais mal elaborados, pela comodidade de escrever tudo em um único local, gerando menos 'trabalho' ou até mesmo pela falta de conhecimento.

> Nota: Em Angular2 isso já muda muito, visto que será muito mais simplificado nesse sentido.

Eu, particularmente, desenvolvo tudo utilizando bem dizer apenas 3 componentes do Angular:

- Controller
- Factory
- Directive

Cada um possui um propósito bem simples, porém bem distinto, veja:

*Factory*: Responsável por obter dados de um `backend`/`api` para alimentar o aplicativo com as informações necessárias.

*Controller*: Responsável por passar os dados (obtidos pelo `factory`) para a view e também por executar funções chamadas pelo usuário através do UI.

*Directive*: Manipulação de HTML condicional e/ou criação de funções padrões comuns em diversas views - Mesmo que as views entre elas não possuam relação alguma.

---

Em um cenário simples, imagine que você possua um E-commerce. Assim que acessamos, precisamos alimentar o site com os produtos. Para isso o `factory` faz a chamada ao `backend` e obtém os dados, armazenando em uma variável ainda dentro do próprio `factory`.

O `controller`, por sua vez, irá buscar essa informação no `factory` - Não se importando como ela foi obtida, só interessa saber que ela existe, então passando para a view através de um `$scope` (ou `vm`, dependendo da `syntax` que você usa), assim alimentamos o site com os produtos.

Supondo que você queira adicionar um produto ao carrinho de compras, mas sabendo que o produto pode ser acessado tanto na home page, como na página de "Mais vendidos", na página "Minha lista", categorias, etc.. Note que é a mesma função sendo chamada de locais diferentes. Sendo assim, podemos aplicar a função em um `directive`, assim ela pode ser chamada independente de sua `view`, `controller` ou outro componente. O próprio carrinho pode ser gerenciado por um `directive` também, sendo que ele é acessado de qualquer `view`.

---

Apesar de "bagunçado", o Angular possui componentes com tarefas e objetivos bem definidos que podem manter sua aplicação enxuta, sem repetições e, de certa forma, bem organizada. Acredito que ele deva ser visto mais como um todo do que como partes isoladas.

---

**Complementar:** Um material que, eu particularmente, usei BASTANTE e que me deu um norte bem bom na organização do meu código e dos meus componentes, foi esse guia: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/i18n/pt-BR.md

Comment: Obrigado Celsom, foi muito esclarecedor. Já utilizo o style guide do John e é muito bom também. Mas nunca tinha olhado para a directive com a visão que você passou, eu só utilizava para componentes visuais e manipulação do DOM. Quando preciso de uma biblioteca própria de funções eu criava um factory Utils e lá eu fazia minhas funções. Não sei se é uma boa abordagem mas funcionou por algum tempo. Com sua explicação eu poderia utilizar os directives para fazer o papel dos objetos com regras que eu pensei?

Comment: De fato o principal objetivo de um directive é a manipulação de DOM. Além do exemplo que citei acima, também já utilizei para uma finalidade semelhante ao que você comentou. Usei para gerenciar login, onde as funções ficavam em um factory e o directive apenas chamava elas. O mesmo directive também manipulava o DOM exibindo, escondendo ou alterando menus e outros objetos de acordo com o nível do usuário ou se o mesmo nem estava online.

Answer (score -2):

[Visão Geral e Conceitual, oficial do Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#controller)

> Lógica de negócios independente da View: Monta-se em Services
>
> > Quando o aplicativo cresce, é uma boa prática mover a lógica independente de exibição do controlador para um serviço, para que ele possa ser reutilizado por outras partes do aplicativo também.

A vantagem de trabalhar com o Angular é a montagem por componentes, desse modo você poderá mudar sua regra de negócio no service e o front-end continuar apresentando os dados sem a necessidade de ajustes tanto na View quanto no controller.